# pass multi dimensional range as parameter python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python and munpy. I have 2 dimesional object mask. It is graphic mak with integer coordinates and value.I want to use part of matrix like:

```
mask[:100,300:]
```

Is it possible to create variable like range = (:100,300:)
and to use like:

```
mask[range]
```

or similar approach

Comment: `range = ":100,300:"` and then `mask[eval(range)]` could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `slice`

```
ranges = slice(0, 100), slice(300, None)
mask[ranges]
```